# ¿Cómo actualizar múltiples grupos de datos utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Necesito actualizar `1000 registros` desde una aplicación Android, estoy enviando los datos al servidor a través del método `GET` desde android con un método `for each` se envían los datos mediante `1000 loops` al siguiente Script PHP.

```
<?php

    DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'USER'); 
    DEFINE ('DBPW', ''); 
    DEFINE ('DBHOST', 'localhost'); 
    DEFINE ('DBNAME', ''); 
    ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
    if (!$dbc) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
            exit();
        }

        $dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
        if (!$dbs) {
            die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
            exit();
        }


    $Tabla = sp_productos;

    $CodigoProducto=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['CodigoProducto']);
    $DescripcionProducto=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['DescripcionProducto']);
    $IdDetalleRefProducto=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['IdDetalleRefProducto']);
    $FechaCreacionProducto=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['FechaCreacionProducto']);
    $FechaActualizacionProducto=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['FechaActualizacionProducto']);
    $IdUser=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['IdUser']);
    $StockInventario=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['StockInventario']);




    $query = "UPDATE $Tabla SET StockInventario='$StockInventario',  DescripcionProducto='$DescripcionProducto' WHERE CodigoProducto='$CodigoProducto' AND IdUser='$IdUser' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Query MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc)); 

    mysqli_close($dbc); 
    echo "Actualizacion Exitosa Amigo";
?>
```

Sin embargo después de correr el código genera el siguiente error:

> ERROR 502 BAD GATEWAY

Creo que es por que se sobrecarga el servidor. quisiera saber, ¿cómo insertar los `1000 registros` de manera optima?

Comment: Buenas a Stack Overflow, exponga más detalle su problema, que no queda muy claro lo que necesita.

Comment: Prueba de poner un delay entre cada petición, así no colapsara su servidor.

Comment: Existen múltiples opciones: 1) Aumentar recursos a tu servidor donde está el servicio. 2) Crear un servicio bulk donde puedas mandar un grupo de elementos y luego procesarlos en grandes fragmentos en lugar de hacerlo 1 por 1. Adicional, el método GET es solo para obtener información, deberías utilizar POST para modificar datos en el servidor.

Comment: @Webserveis un delay no es la solución correcta para este escenario.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Como podria crear el servicio BULK que te refieres?

Comment: Si cambias a POST, podrías enviar en el cuerpo de la petición una lista con los elementos que necesitas procesar. Luego, de lado de PHP, parseas la cadena JSON a arreglos asociativos de PHP y procesas cada elemento del arreglo principal.

Answer (score 1):

La solución seria no utilizar el foreach y hacer 1 llamada por iteracion. Asumo que utilizas un foreach porque antes de enviarlo lo validas, así que en vez de eso crea un JSON. Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
var datos = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < tuLista.length; i++){
   if(validaAlgo){
        datos.push
              ({
                 CodigoProducto:tuLista[i]["CodigoProducto"],
                 ....
              });
   }
}

$.ajax({
        url: SLServer+url,
        xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
        },
        data: JSON.stringfy(datos);,
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function( json ) {
            algo(json);
        },
        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                error(errorThrown);
        }
 });
```

Asi envías todo en 1 sola llamada a tu servidor. Para darte un codigo mas fiel necesitaria saber el cotexto completo de la app android, este ejemplo es con javascript, pero puede ser pasado a java.